# Update 1 table-col using 2 table-col from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it possible to update `1 column/field` of my table using `2 column/field` from other table?

i tried this query :

```
UPDATE TEMP_Quantity
SET SS = (SELECT Qty1, Qty2 FROM Table_Quantity
WHERE Id = @IdHolder AND ProductId = 7)
WHERE Id = @IdHolder
```

And Sql said this error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

SS = NVarchar (Because it can accept number or string base on the column that i will select)

can someone tell me the right way to do this? tia :)

Comment: what should be store in `SS`, sum of both Quantities

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Your field SS can only take one number (I expect that SS is an integer), not two.

Comment: @JaydipJ the combined Quantity. Sample `Qty1 = 10` and `Qty2 = 3` then `SS = 103`.

Comment: SELECT SUM(Qty1,Qty2)

Comment: uhm... you want to concat quantities? how is that useful?

Comment: @Stephen i will use it for eggs. example Qty1 = 1Tray of egg and Qty2 = #Pcs of egg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm... to answer your question, you can `CONCAT` both qty's

```
UPDATE t1
SET SS = CONCAT(t2.Qty1, t2.Qty2) 
FROM TEMP_Quantity t1 
INNER JOIN Table_Quantity t2 on t2.Id = t1.Id
WHERE t1.Id = @IdHolder
AND  t2.ProductId = 7
```

But this just feels wrong.

Comment: it mean `concat` will combine the 2 value of that 2 specif column?

Comment: yes, as in your comments, if you have `Qty1=10` and `Qty2=3` then `SS = 103`

Comment: Concat appends one string to another.

Comment: @muffi that is the requirement.

Comment: it works my friend. I am right that this problem is so easy but still didn't find the solution :) thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
UPDATE TEMP_Quantity
SET SS = (SELECT CAST(Qty1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(Qty2 AS VARCHAR(10)) 
          FROM Table_Quantity
          WHERE Id = @IdHolder AND ProductId = 7)
WHERE Id = @IdHolder
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use and examine the below script. I hope, it is usefull for you.

```
declare @qty1 int
declare @qty2 int

if object_id('tempdb..#dbDestination') is not null
    drop table #dbDestination

create table #dbDestination(
Id int,
ss nvarchar(50)
)

if object_id('tempdb..#dbSource') is not null
    drop table #dbSource

create table #dbSource(
Id int,
ProductId int,
qty1 int,
qty2 int
)

insert into #dbDestination(Id,ss) values (1,null),(2,null)
insert into #dbSource(Id,ProductId,qty1,qty2) values(1,7,10,3), (2,null,8,2)

UPDATE #dbDestination
SET SS = (
            SELECT CAST(qty1 as nvarchar(50))+ cast(qty2 as nvarchar(50)) 
            FROM #dbSource
            WHERE Id = 1 AND ProductId = 7
        )
WHERE Id = 1

select * from #dbDestination
```